# Is there a way of setting TLS Version using the redshift-connector driver in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, amazon-redshift

We're currently using the redshift-connector driver in Python to connect to a a Redshift database.

This is working locally however when deploying to a server with limited internet connectivity we're seeing SSL handshake errors.

When observing this on Wireshark we see locally the handshake uses TLSv1.2, however on the server we see TLSv1 and no response which we believe is the culprit. Is there a way of specifying the TLS version on a connection made with the redshift-connector?

Code:

```
import redshift_connector

connection = redshift_connector.connect(
            host='hostip',
            database='db',
            user=’username’,
            password=’password’,
            timeout=120
         )
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redshift.py", line 9, in <module>
    timeout=20
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\redshift_connector\__init__.py", line 334, in connect
    credentials_provider=info.credentials_provider,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\redshift_connector\core.py", line 587, in __init__
    raise InterfaceError("communication error", e)
redshift_connector.error.InterfaceError: ('communication error', timeout('_ssl.c:1074: The handshake operation timed out'))
```

We've verified the port is open via telnet so this isn't a firewall issue. Additionally we used ssl=false and can connect without any problems but would prefer this to be enabled

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: This could be a permissions issue at the firewall.  Have you checked to make sure your server has a route to the redshift instance?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver/blob/master/tutorials/001%20-%20Connecting%20to%20Amazon%20Redshift.ipynb

Comment: Yes, there is a route to the server which we verified using telnet. Additionally when we disable ssl it is able to connect but this isn't a viable solution for us

Comment: In your example there are not authentication keys... did you provide them with your connection?

Comment: No, authentication keys are only required when using IAM credentials. The example uses standard db credentials to authenticate

Comment: So you are using SSL, is your SSL keys signed?  If not are you using `ssl_insecure=True`

Comment: It is signed yes. If you use the flag ssl_insecure=True you are required to authenticate via IAM.